# Confusions on effective action and 1PI 3-point Green's function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, 1pi-effective-action

In Peskin's QFT book chapter 11.5, the author gives a graph(see below) and claims that the third functional derivative for effective action $\Gamma$ gives the 1PI (one-particle-irreducible) 3-point Greens's function.

[image]

When computing the electron propagtor, I learned that the full electron propagtor is a geometric series of 1PI bubble(1PI bubble=sum of all 1PI diagrams).

So how can I see that the white bubble is the 1PI 3-point Green's function? Is it a geometric series of something? What does the white bubble contain?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146734/2451