# Relation between Feynman diagrams and the effective action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

I have learned that the effective action can be obtained from legendre transforming the generating function $$W(J) = \ln(Z(J)),$$ which corresponds to connected graphs. However I don't quite get an idea of why effective action corresponds to one-particle-irreducible (1PI) graphs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146734/2451

Comment: The first chapter of Damiano Anselmi's free textbook `Renormalization' has a good discussion of this and some more advanced things about generating functionals

Comment: $\uparrow$ p. 34-39.