# Why doesn't this diagram appear in the partition function in zero-dimensional QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, propagator, partition-function

For the zero-dimensional QFT with action
$$S(\phi)=\frac{\alpha}{2}\phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4-J\phi,\tag{1}$$
we can perturbatively expand the partition function as
$$Z_\lambda(J)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\phi~e^{-S}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r!}\left(\frac{-\lambda}{4!}\right)^r\left(\frac{\partial^4}{\partial J^4}\right)^r\exp\left(\frac{J^2}{2\alpha}\right),\tag{2}$$
which at first order in $\lambda$ gives
$$-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\left(\frac{J^4}{\alpha^4}+\frac{6J^2}{\alpha^3}+\frac{3}{\alpha^2}\right).\tag{3}$$

This can be expressed via the diagrams

[image: Three connected Feynman diagrams with one vertex]

since we know we need one vertex and to contract in line with Wick's theorem. What I'm unsure about is why we can't also have the disconnected diagram

[image: A disconnected Feynman diagram with one vertex]

since it has the same number of sources, propagators and vertices as the second diagram above. This diagram does show up when calculating the second moment $\langle\phi^2\rangle$ using the partition function.

Comment: The last diagram does not contribute to $\langle \phi^2\rangle$. It does contribute to $Z \langle \phi^2\rangle$, and dividing by $Z$ has the effect of removing such diagrams. This is basic diagrammatics, and you should read any introductory book on QFT for a start.

Comment: as answered by @Qmechanic, you need to series expand (or at least include) the exponential in (2) as well in order to get the full J dependence in (3).

Comment: @Wakabaloola Thank you, I see it now! In the lecture course I'm taking at this point $\langle \phi^2\rangle$ was defined to include the partition function, and later on we redefine the normalisation by dividing by the partition function. I had completely missed that the exp term was in one of my expressions but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Well, OP partition function $Z[J]$ does in fact contain disconnected diagrams, such as, e.g. OP's last diagram $8|$, cf. the [linked cluster theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324252/2451) $Z[J]=\exp(\frac{i}{\hbar}W_c[J])$.

Concretely, the propagator $|$ in OP's last diagram $8|$ comes from the bag $\exp\left(\frac{J^2}{2\alpha}\right)$ of propagators in OP's eq. (2).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the linked cluster theorem. I'm confused however as to how there can be more diagrams contributing to the partition function at order $J^2$ as the second diagram in my post, when accounting for the symmetry factor of 4 agrees with the explicit calculation. Wouldn't any further diagrams give something that disagrees with this?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $S(\phi,J) = S_0(\phi) + S_{\rm int}(\phi) - J \phi$ with $S_0(\phi) = \alpha \phi^2/2$ and $S_{\rm int}(\phi) = \lambda \phi^4\!/4!$, the generating function(al) of the full model (including the interaction term) is given by $$ Z(J) = \frac{\int \! d \phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)} e ^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} e^{J \phi}}{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)}e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)}} =: \left\langle e^{J \phi} \right\rangle,$$ which can be rewritten as  $$Z(J) = \frac{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)} e^{- S_{\rm int}(\phi)} e^{J \phi}}{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)} } \cdot \frac{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)} }{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)}e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} } = \frac{\left\langle  e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} e^{J\phi} \right\rangle_0 }{ \left\langle e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)}  \right\rangle_0}, $$ where $\left\langle  f(\phi) \right\rangle_0$ denotes the Gaussian mean value defined by $$\left\langle f(\phi) \right\rangle_0 := \frac{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)} f(\phi)}{\int \! d\phi \, e^{-S_0(\phi)}}.  $$ The perturbative expansion of the term $\left\langle e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} e^{J \phi}\right\rangle_0$ is given by $$ \left\langle e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} e^{J\phi} \right\rangle_0 =  e^{-S_{\rm int}(\partial_J)} \left\langle e^{J\phi}\right\rangle_0 = e^{-S_{\rm int}(\partial_J)}  Z_0(J), $$ with the generating function of the free theory $Z_0(J)= \left\langle e^{J \phi} \right\rangle_0 = e^{J^2/2 \alpha}$, leading to the compact expression $$ Z(J) = \frac{e^{-S_{\rm int} (\partial_J)}Z_0(J)}{e^{-S_{\rm int}(\partial_J)}Z_0(J) \Large|_{J=0}}. $$ Expanding up to terms linear in $\lambda$, one finds $$e^{-S_{\rm int}(\partial_J)}Z_0(J) = e^{J^2/2\alpha} \left[1-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\left(\frac{J^4}{\alpha^4}  +\frac{6 J^2}{\alpha^3}+\frac{3}{\alpha^2}\right) +\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2) \right].$$ With the help of the comments, you had realized yourself that you had simply forgotten the exponential term $e^{J^2/2 \alpha}$ in this expression. Note that the term in the denominator, $$e^{-S_{\rm int}(\partial_J)} Z_0(J) {\large|}_{J=0} = 1 -\frac{\lambda}{4!} \frac{3}{\alpha^2}+ \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2),$$ cancels all graphs with disconnected vacuum bubbles (like your last diagram), arriving at  $$Z(J) = e^{J^2/2 \alpha} \left[  1 - \frac{\lambda}{4!} \left( \frac{J^4}{\alpha^4} + \frac{6 J^2}{\alpha^3}  \right)+ \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2) \right]$$ and $\left\langle \phi^2 \right\rangle =1/\alpha - \lambda/2 \alpha^3 +\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$.

Alternatively, employing the Wick theorem, you find $$\left\langle \phi^2 \right\rangle =\frac{\left\langle e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} \phi^2 \right\rangle_0}{\left\langle e^{-S_{\rm int}(\phi)} \right\rangle_0 } = \frac{\left\langle \phi^2 \right\rangle_0 - \frac{\lambda}{4!} \left\langle \phi^6 \right\rangle_0+ \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)}{1 - \frac{\lambda}{4!} \left\langle \phi^4\right\rangle_0 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)} = \frac{\frac{1}{\alpha}- \frac{\lambda}{4!} \frac{15}{\alpha^3}+ \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)}{1- \frac{\lambda}{4!} \frac{3}{\alpha^2}+ \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)} = \frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{\lambda}{2 \alpha^3} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2),$$ in agreement with the previous result.